# Oracle XE ( 11.2.0 ) Database Configuration failed on Ubunto 14 and 16

Tags: database, oracle, configuration, oracle-xe

I am facing Error while configuring Oracle XE after installation.
I Follow this Tutorial

https://askubuntu.com/questions/566734/how-to-install-oracle-11gr2-on-ubuntu-14-04

When I run this statement for database Configuration.

```
/etc/init.d/oracle-xe configure
```

I face this Error after input ports and password

```
Do you want Oracle Database 11g Express Edition to be started on boot (y/n) [y]:y

Starting Oracle Net Listener...Done
Configuring database...

**Database Configuration failed.  Look into /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/config/log for details**
```

I guess it maybe  memory Target size issue.
I Tried this

```
nano /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/config/scripts/init.ora
comment # memory_target=100663296
```

but It won't work work for me.

**Error Log.**

```
PostDbCreation.log

    begin
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01034: ORACLE not available 
Process ID: 0 
Session ID: 0 Serial number: 0 



File created.

ORA-01034: ORACLE not available
ORA-27101: shared memory realm does not exist
Linux-x86_64 Error: 2: No such file or directory
ORA-00845: MEMORY_TARGET not supported on this system
select 'utl_recomp_begin: ' || to_char(sysdate, 'HH:MI:SS') from dual
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01034: ORACLE not available 
Process ID: 0 
Session ID: 0 Serial number: 0 


BEGIN utl_recomp.recomp_serial(); END;

*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01034: ORACLE not available 
Process ID: 0 
Session ID: 0 Serial number: 0 


select 'utl_recomp_end: ' || to_char(sysdate, 'HH:MI:SS') from dual
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01034: ORACLE not available 
Process ID: 0 
Session ID: 0 Serial number: 0
```

Answer (score 1):

The best would be to start from the beginning.

Step 1 - Installation of SSH server

```
sudo apt install openssh-server
```

Step 2 - Execute the following commands (pre-requisite packages)

```
sudo apt-get install alien libaio1 unixodbc vim
```

Step 3 - Download the Oracle 11g express edition setup file from Oracle website     http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/database-technologies/express-edition/downloads/index.html . Then go to folder where you have downloaded the setup file (rpm) and convert it to debian type (deb):

```
sudo alien --scripts -d oracle-xe-11.2.0-1.0.x86_64.rpm
```

Step 4 - Execute the pre-requisites, 
Create a special chkconfig script:

```
sudo vim /sbin/chkconfig
```

and add following into the file:

```
#!/bin/bash
file=/etc/init.d/oracle-xe
if [[ ! `tail -n1 $file | grep INIT` ]]; then
echo >> $file
echo '### BEGIN INIT INFO' >> $file
echo '# Provides: OracleXE' >> $file
echo '# Required-Start: $remote_fs $syslog' >> $file
echo '# Required-Stop: $remote_fs $syslog' >> $file
echo '# Default-Start: 2 3 4 5' >> $file
echo '# Default-Stop: 0 1 6' >> $file
echo '# Short-Description: Oracle 11g Express Edition' >> $file
echo '### END INIT INFO' >> $file
fi
update-rc.d oracle-xe defaults 80 01
```

Save the above file and provide appropriate permissions

```
sudo chmod 755 /sbin/chkconfig
```

Execute the following commands:

```
free -m
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/awk /bin/awk
mkdir /var/lock/subsys
touch /var/lock/subsys/listener
```

Execute the below which prevents oracle installation errors. It is weird but helped in my case. Ignore errors that will appear.

```
sudo -s
umount /dev/shm
sudo rm -rf /dev/shm 
sudo mkdir /dev/shm
mount --move /run/shm /dev/shm
sudo mount -t tmpfs shmfs -o size=2048m /dev/shm
```

Step 5 - Create the below file,

```
sudo vim /etc/rc2.d/S01shm_load
```

Copy content below into the opened file:

```
#!/bin/sh case "$1" 
in start) mkdir /var/lock/subsys 2>/dev/null 
touch /var/lock/subsys/listener 
rm /dev/shm 2>/dev/null 
mkdir /dev/shm 2>/dev/null 
mount -t tmpfs shmfs -o size=2048m /dev/shm ;;
*) echo error 
exit 1 ;; 
esac
```

Execute the following command

```
sudo chmod 755 /etc/rc2.d/S01shm_load
```

Step 6 - Restart the machine.

Step 7 - Install Oracle 11gR2 XE. Go to the directory where you created the ubuntu package file and enter following commands (not as root user),

```
sudo dpkg --install oracle-xe_11.2.0-2_amd64.deb

sudo /etc/init.d/oracle-xe configure
```

Enter the following configuration information:

Valid HTTP port for the Oracle Application Express (the default is 8080, use 7070)

Valid port for the Oracle database listener (the default is 1521)

Password for the SYS and SYSTEM administrative user accounts

Confirm password for SYS and SYSTEM administrative user accounts

Whether you want the database to start automatically when the computer starts, Y

Step 8 - Before you start using Oracle 11gR2 XE you have to set-up few things more. 
Change to users home directory (type cd) 
Open bashrc using the command

```
vim .bashrc
```

Add following lines to .bashrc :

```
export ORACLE_HOME=/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe 
export ORACLE_SID=XE 
export NLS_LANG=`$ORACLE_HOME/bin/nls_lang.sh` 
export ORACLE_BASE=/u01/app/oracle 
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH 
export PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

Execute .profile to load the changes:

```
. ./.profile
```

Open root bash using

```
sudo vim /root/.bashrc
```

and copy the same contents at the end of that file

Step 9 - Restart the appliance. Oracle should have been started now

Step 10 - Execute the following command to enter SQL prompt

```
sqlplus sys as sysdba﻿
```

Answer (score 0):

Once investigated the log files prompted in the log files, was able to notice that the `DB_RECOVERY_FILE_DEST` desitination directory in `/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/config/scripts/init*` are not exist. So I manually created the directory.

In my case

```
sudo mkdir /u01/app/oracle/fast_recovery_area
```

This has been applied within both `init.ora` and `initXETemp.ora`.
Restarted the Laptop and started the the configuration again.

`/etc/init.d/oracle-xe configure`

Above completed the configuration successfully for me.